# Which Wi-Fi chips/modules support the 802.11s standard?

Tags: networking, wifi, mesh-network

I'm very interested in the Mesh technology and the (new) IEEE Mesh standard 802.11s. I've looked for some Wi-Fi modules which support the standard but it's never mentioned, although the standard was published at the end of 2011.
I also have read about the open802.11s solution (http://open80211s.org/open80211s/), but there are also no Wi-Fi modules mentioned. So I have the following questions:

1. Does this mean that all Modules support it and you only have to get the correct driver (mac80211)?
2. I've read about the Linux Kernel which supports the 11s standard. Are there all parts implemented?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. As it stands, this question is way too broad. Question 2/3 is off-topic here, as questions asking for third-party resources attract spam and opinionated answers. Question 5 is vague and broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this page [drivers](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers) for a list of drivers and whether or not they support mesh networking. You can find `ath9k`, `b43`, among others that support mesh - but Intel `iwlwifi` doesn't. From those drivers, you can find corresponding chipsets that are expected to work on that mode.

Note, however, mesh networking currently implemented in the kernel does not necessarily support all features found in the `802.11s` standard (now part of `802.11-2012`).